# WCF SecurityNegotiationException by trying remote access

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Webservice deployed on IIS 6. I deployed it now buy create a WebSite and use the default settings.

I can see the DNSService.svc?wsdl in my Webbrowser so i can access this site. But if i make a WebReference in my VS project and try to run a method of the WebService the programm runs in a SecurityNegotiationException. The Messagetext said something like the caller couldn't be authed by the Webservice. But why is my access dined? i dindt setup a password or ssl or something

How could i change the behavior of the webservice so i could talk to him.

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="DnsClient.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="UltraVNC" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\UltraVNC\vncviewer.edxe" />
    <add key="CustomerConfigsPath" value="D:\" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IDNSService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text"
          textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
            enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="">
              <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never" />
            </transport>
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
              algorithmSuite="Default" establishSecurityContext="true" />
          </security>
        </binding>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://hostnotshownhere/DNSService.svc"
        binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IDNSService1"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IDNSService" name="WSHttpBinding_IDNSService">
        <identity>
          <dns value="localhost" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was the binding type! wsHTTPBinding only works in a Domain. For usage in the Internet i had to set up HTTPBinding like that

```
<bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IDNSService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm=""/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://MyServer/MyService.svc"
        binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IDNSService"
        contract="ServiceReference1.IDNSService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IDNSService" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

hope this could help somebody

Comment: In which file, can you provide more description that just same xml?